# libc.so.6 version error

Tags: shared-library

I was installing node-red and it gave me an error stating that the library `libatomic.so.1` was missing but i had it in one of my directories.

After some searching i found out that i had to edit the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file to include the directory where it was installed.

Once i did that, and used the `ldconfig -v` command, i noticed that it had overwritten some libraries which is an issue.

Now i cant use any basic command such as `sudo`,`mv`,`rm`,`chmod`,`nano` etc. Whenever i do use the commands i get this error :

```
  chmod: /opt/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found(required by chmod)
```

Now, i know the newer version of the library is stored in one of `/lib/` and `/usr/lib` folders but i don't know how to link them again since nano and `ldconfig` both wont work.

`apt-get` does not work on this machine too. when i try using `uname` or `unlink` it gives me `segmentation fault`. Is there Any workaround for this?

Edit : I tried rebooting it and ssh-ing into it and now i cant reach the device at all

Comment: After a reboot unfortunately it won’t be possible to fix this without using a recovery system of some sort.

Comment: @StephenKitt what recovery system can i use?

Comment: I don’t know, since this is a remote device it depends on your setup — *e.g.* if it’s a hosted system, whether there’s a recovery console, or if you have the ability to boot from a recovery image.

Comment: @StephenKitt thank you for your comment. i have factory reset the machine and it is back to normal now.